# What is the key difference between Visual Studio Code - Exploration and Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently started using Visual Studio Code, but have had problems using it when not connected to The Web. So I've heard of VS Code - Exploration, which managed to solve that problem with ease. Besides the need for connection, what are the other differences between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply uses a newer version of [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) and a 1-2 month ahead (just like [Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)).

> Besides the need for connection

This was just a bug with Electron.